# Fast way to count smaller/equal/larger elements in array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, optimization, binary-search

I need to optimize my algorithm for counting larger/smaller/equal numbers in array(unsorted), than a given number.

I have to do this a lot of times and given array also can have thousands of elements.

Array doesn't change, number is changing

Example:

array: 1,2,3,4,5

n = 3

- Number of <: 2
- Number of >: 2
- Number of ==:1

**First thought:**

Iterate through the array and check if element is > or < or == than n.
**O(n*k)**

### Possible optimization:

**O((n+k) * logn)**

Firstly sort the array (im using c qsort), then use binary search to find equal number, and then somehow count smaller and larger values. But how to do that?

If elements exists (bsearch returns pointer to the element) I also need to check if array contain possible duplicates of this elements (so I need to check before and after this elements while they are equal to found element), and then use some pointer operations to count larger and smaller values.
How to get number of values larger/smaller having a pointer to equal element? 
But what to do if I don't find the value (bsearch returns null)?

Comment: If you need to do it with only one/few `n`, then your "optimization" is actually "de-optimization".

Comment: Sorting, with luck and a good algo is O(n logn), whatever you do afterwards will make that worse. Scanning once through the array, incrementing three counters, would be O(n). Where is the optimisation you want to achieve?

Comment: But in best case (no duplicates) i think im saving a lot of time

Comment: You *think*? Prove it then. There is a well established scientific notation for this stuff.

Comment: so is there any better way to do this instead O(n) ?

Comment: No. You have to check the whole array in any case.

Comment: So.. you have actually taken the answer and edited it into the question, invalidating everything said.... And pretty much removing the point of the question itself. It's not clear now what you are asking.

Comment: i dont know what to do if bsearch returns null

Comment: So your real question is "how to use `bsearch` function?" and not the whole thing above. And I think this function is not very suitable for your purpose. You don't want to search for the exact element.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i also wanted to know if my idea is good, i tagged bsearch because its related with my quesion

Comment: (`how to [get number of elements lower/higher]` with C++, there'd be `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` - any special reason to use C?)

Comment: @greybeard i have no problem with cpp, thanks i will check it

Comment: "I have to do this a lot of times and given array also can have thousands of elements." still lacks clarity.  On repeated runs, does `k` change? does  `array` change?

Comment: array doesnt change, number is changing @chux

Comment: One more thought - if the array is unchanging, you can multi-thread it without too much issue as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array is unsorted, and the numbers in it have no other useful properties, there is no way to beat an O(n) approach of walking the array once, and counting items in the three buckets.

Sorting the array followed by a binary search would be no better than O(n), assuming that you employ a sort algorithm that is linear in time (e.g. a radix sort). For comparison-based sorts, such as quicksort, the timing would increase to O(n`*`log<sub>2</sub>n).

On the other hand, sorting would help if you need to run multiple queries against the same set of numbers. The timing for k queries against n numbers would go from O(n`*`k) for k linear searches to O(n+k`*`log<sub>2</sub>n) assuming a linear-time sort, or O((n+k)`*`log<sub>2</sub>n) with comparison-based sort. Given a sufficiently large k, the average query time would go down.

Comment: @klm That's an important detail that you left out.  Please update your question describing what you're **really** trying to do.

Comment: So it will depend on how the number of times relative to the array size.

Comment: Why `O(n + k log n)`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `n log n` for sorting, `k log n` for `k` binary searches.

Comment: @EugeneSh. isn't that `O((n+k)log n)`, then?

Comment: so do you have the way to count larger or smaller when bsearch returns null?

Comment: @greybeard Oh, that... Sure.

Comment: @klm You will need to implement your own binary search that looks for the insertion position, rather than using `bsearch`. Fortunately, this is one of the easier algorithms to implement :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight insertion of what?

Comment: @klm Insertion position of the missing element to maintain the order of the sequence. E.g. in a sequence of 1 2 4 8 10 15 the insertion position of 7 would be 3 (between 4 and 8).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i dont understand, im not inserting anything :(

Comment: @klm Binary search algorithm answers the question "if I wanted to maintain the order of the sequence, where would I insert a given number into it?" Please make sure you understand the example that I gave you in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since the array is (apparently?) not changing, presort it.  This allows a binary search (Log(n))

   a.) implement your own version of bsearch (it will be less code anyhow)

   - you can do it inline using indices vs. pointers
   - you won't need function pointers to a specialized function

   b.) Since you say that you want to count the number of matches, you imply that the array can contain multiple entries with the same value (otherwise you would have used a boolean has_n).

   - This means you'll need to do a linear search for the beginning and end of the array of "n"s.
   - From which you can calculate the number less than n and greater than n.
   - It appears that you have some unwritten algorithm for choosing these (for n=3 you look for count of values greater and less than 2 and equal to 1, so there is no way to give specific code)

   c.)  For further optimization (at the expense of memory) you can sort the data into a binary search tree of structs that holds not just the value, but also the count and the number of values before and after each value.  It may not use more memory at all if you have a lot of repeat values, but it is hard to tell without the dataset.
2. That's as much as I can help without code that describes your hidden algorithms and data or at least a sufficient description (aside from recommending a course or courses in data structures and algorithms).

Comment: thanks, now i need to find out how to rewrite binary search that returns the index, but doesnt checks equality. so "look for n, if exist return index, if not exixst return index where it should be" and after calling this check equality